# What are things that the Federal Reserve can do that a member state's central bank cannot do, because of the ECB?

Tags: european-union, central-bank

> The ECB Governing Council makes monetary policy for the Eurozone and
> the European Union, administers the foreign exchange reserves of EU
> member states, engages in foreign exchange operations, and defines the
> intermediate monetary objectives and key interest rate of the EU. The
> ECB Executive Board enforces the policies and decisions of the
> Governing Council, and may direct the national central banks when
> doing so.[3] The ECB has the exclusive right to authorise the issuance
> of euro banknotes. Member states can issue euro coins, but the volume
> must be approved by the ECB beforehand. The bank also operates the
> payments system.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Central_Bank

Aside making monetary policy for the Eurozone and the European Union, administering the foreign exchange reserves of EU member states, engaging in foreign exchange operations, and defining the intermediate monetary objectives and key interest rate of the EU, and authorizing the issuance of banknotes, what are things that the Federal Reserve can do that a member state's central bank cannot do, because of the ECB?

It's obvious that the power and authority of EU member states' central banks are lesser than those of countries that are not part of an economic union, but I would like to understand to what extent their authority and power are diminished.

Comment: A good starting point would to look at the list of ECB powers vs *European* national central bank powers.  Anything that's in the ECB prerogatives would normally be a central bank's.

Comment: A better question might be to compare the Federal Reserve *System* with the ECB and Eurosystem, and then the 12 Federal Reserve *Banks* with the 20 national central banks.